# Google Tag Manager malware warning caused by tracking pixel from our safe domain

Tags: google, google-tag-manager, malware

I send my tracking pixel code to a client that uses Google Tag Manager (GTM). Once he added the pixel as a custom HTML he got a malware warning after a few hours.

We already have a link with the same domain that works on Google AdWords. They told us our domain is safe from malware. We added the pixel in our GTM account we didn't get any warning messages.

What can we do?